# Quotes became invalid in .zshrc file

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

In my .zshrc file, if I add

`alias vii=“mvim -v”`

or
`alias vii=‘mvim -v’`

---

After I used command `vii`, the terminal displayed:

`zsh: command not found: “mvim`

or
`zsh: command not found: ‘mvim`

---

If I put

`alias vii=mvim -v`

Then, command`vii` works as `mvim` without `-v`

---

Same, in my .zshrc file,

`ZSH_THEME=robbyrussell` works.

`ZSH_THEME=“robbyrussell"` doesn't work

Why quotes became invalid in the .zshrc file?
How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ASCII quotes, not the curly quotes your editor is inserting.

Compare

```
alias vii=“mvim -v”   # wrong
```

with

```
alias vii="mvim -v"   # right
```